# Inserting into SQL Database more than once

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am making a code generator that makes a new code and then querys a database to see if it exists.  If it does, try again to make a different code.  If it doesn't exist, add it into the database.  But when I add the one code into the database, the query adds 3 different rows with 3 different values.  One of the values, is the one supposed to be added, and the other two I don't know where they come from.  Why is it inserting 3 when I only set it to add one.  My full class file is:

```
package com.xium.accesscode;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import com.xium.log.ServerLogger;
import com.xium.sql.DBConnections;
import com.xium.utils.StringUtils;

public class NewAccessCode {

static String AccessCodeDBuser = "root";
static String AccessCodeDBpass = "";
static String AccessCodeDBhost = "localhost";

static String newAccessCode;
static String randS;
static String randFinal;

static int min = 000000000;
static int max = 999999999;
static int randI;

public static void AccessCode() {
    if(newAccessCode() == 0) {
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[ALERT] Database Error");
    } else if(newAccessCode() == 1) {
        //Reruns the code generator, to make a unique code
        newAccessCode();
    } else if(newAccessCode() == 2) {
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[NOTE] New Access Code: " + newAccessCode);
    }
}

/*
 * Return Codes:
 * 0 - Database Error
 * 1 - Code Already Exists
 * 2 - New Access Code Added
 */

private static int newAccessCode() {
    genAccessCode();
    newAccessCode = randFinal;

    //Does it already exist?
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet results = null;
    String statement = "SELECT count(*) FROM `xium`.`accesscodes` WHERE `accesscode`='" + newAccessCode + "'";
    String statement2 = "INSERT INTO `xium`.`accesscodes` (`accesscode`, `used`, `assignedto`) VALUES ('" + newAccessCode + "', '0', '')";

    try {
        connection = DBConnections.getAccessCodeDB(AccessCodeDBuser, AccessCodeDBpass, AccessCodeDBhost);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement);
        results = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        results.next();

        if(results.getInt(1) == 0) {

        } else if(results.getInt(1) >= 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        connection = DBConnections.getAccessCodeDB(AccessCodeDBuser, AccessCodeDBpass, AccessCodeDBhost);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(statement2);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return 2;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

private static String genAccessCode() {
    randI = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    randS = randI + "";
    randFinal = StringUtils.toMD5(randS);
    return randFinal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run your AccessCode() function, the if statements are running the statement as well. So don't do:

```
if(newAccessCode() == 0)
```

You should make a new integer value set equal to the value of your newAccessCode() function and then check the value of the int.

So:

```
int returnValue = newAccessCode();
```

Then check the value of the returnValue.

```
if(returnValue == 0)
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a call to newAccessCode() method in AccessCode() static method three times.
Change that to

```
public static void AccessCode() {
int newAccessCodeReturn = newAccessCode();
    if(newAccessCodeR`enter code here`eturn  == 0) {
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[ALERT] Database Error");
    } else if(newAccessCodeReturn  == 1) {
        //Reruns the code generator, to make a unique code
        newAccessCode();
    } else if(newAccessCodeReturn  == 2) {
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[NOTE] New Access Code: " + newAccessCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `newAccessCode()` repeatedly in your `if/else if` code. Every time you do this it inserts into the DB. Call it once and save the result in a variable.

```
int result = newAccessCode();
if(result == 0) {
    ServerLogger.writeLog("[ALERT] Database Error");
} else if(result == 1) {
    //Reruns the code generator, to make a unique code
    newAccessCode();
} else if(result == 2) {
    ServerLogger.writeLog("[NOTE] New Access Code: " + newAccessCode);
}
```

or use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (newAccessCode()) {
    case 0:
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[ALERT] Database Error");
        break;
    case 1:
        //Reruns the code generator, to make a unique code
        newAccessCode();
        break;
    case 2:
        ServerLogger.writeLog("[NOTE] New Access Code: " + newAccessCode);
        break;
}
```